# Campo tipo data em formulário Codegniter

Tags: php, html5, codeigniter

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário com campo tipo data.

Como eu uso o recurso do form presente do Codeigniter para um campo data?

No exemplo abaixo estou usando text area. Existe uma função `form_` para datas?

```
 echo " <div class='form-group'>    ";
            $atributos = array(
                "class" =>  "col-sm-2 control-label"
            );          
            echo form_label("Data de início:","DATA_INICIO",$atributos);
            echo "<div class='col-sm-10'>";
            $atributos = array(
                "name"  =>  "DATA_INICIO",
                "id"    =>  "DATA_INICIO",
                "placeholder" => "Descreva o diagnóstico por dia realizado",
                "class" => "form-control",
                "value" =>  set_value('DATA_INICIO')
            );
            $formdate
            echo form_textarea($atributos);
            echo " </div>";
        echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 2):

No CodeIgniter, mediante a documentação para a sua última versão 2.2.0, não existe nenhum *helper* para formulários que permita gerar campos para os novos tipos introduzidos com o HTML5.

#### [Documentação para Form Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Contudo, visto ser algo muito necessário nos dias actuais, já outros passaram por esse problema e criaram soluções.

Um exemplo pode ser encontrado no fórum do CodeIgniter com o nome [Extended form helper to support HTML5 form elements](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/191543/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> cujo mesmo segue em baixo:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


/**
 * Common Input Field
 *
 * @access    public
 * @param    string
 * @param    mixed
 * @param    string
 * @param    string
 * @return    string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('form_common'))
{
    function form_common($type = 'text', $data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
        $defaults = array('type' => $type, 'name' => (( ! is_array($data)) ? $data : ''), 'value' => $value);

        return "<input "._parse_form_attributes($data, $defaults).$extra." />";
    }
}

/**
 * Email Input Field
 *
 * @access    public
 * @param    mixed
 * @param    string
 * @param    string
 * @return    string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('form_email'))
{
    function form_email($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
        return form_common($type = 'email', $data = '', $value = '', $extra = '');
    }
}

/**
 * Url Input Field
 *
 * @access    public
 * @param    mixed
 * @param    string
 * @param    string
 * @return    string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('form_url'))
{
    function form_url($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
        return form_common($type = 'url', $data = '', $value = '', $extra = '');
    }
}

/**
 * Number Input Field
 *
 * @access    public
 * @param    mixed
 * @param    string
 * @param    string
 * @return    string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('form_number'))
{
    function form_number($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
        return form_common($type = 'number', $data = '', $value = '', $extra = '');
    }
}

/**
 * Number Input Field
 *
 * @access    public
 * @param    mixed
 * @param    string
 * @param    string
 * @return    string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('form_range'))
{
    function form_range($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
        return form_common($type = 'range', $data = '', $value = '', $extra = '');
    }
}


/* End of file MY_form_helper.php */
/* Location: ./application/helpers/MY_form_helper.php */
```

Para o teu caso em particular de forma a criares um `input[type=data]` deverás adicionar ao ficheiro em cima referênciado:

```
/**
 * Date Input Field
 *
 * @access    public
 * @param    mixed
 * @param    string
 * @param    string
 * @return    string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('form_date'))
{
    function form_date($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
        return form_common($type = 'date', $data = '', $value = '', $extra = '');
    }
}
```

Comment: Grato pelo retorno! Valeu!